# Why I change the code in a better foramt but it run a error in QtSpim

Tags: mips, qtspim

I put the code and error here:

```
.data
skA:       .asciiz "\nEnter a : "
askB:      .asciiz "\nEnter b : "
askC:      .asciiz "\nEnter c : "
askX:      .asciiz "\nEnter x : "
result:    .asciiz "\nResult is : "

.text
.globl main
main:
         li $v0,4
         la $a0,askA         #it will print prompt
         syscall
         li $v0,5
         syscall             #ask user input
         move $t1,$v0        #save a to t1


         li $v0,4
         la $a0,askB         #it will print prompt
         syscall        
         li $v0,5
         syscall             #ask user input
         move $t2,$v0        #save a to t1


         li $v0,4
         la $a0,askC         #it will print prompt
         syscall        
         li $v0,5
         syscall             #ask user input
         move $t3,$v0        #save a to t1

         li $v0,4
         la $a0,askX         #it will print prompt
         syscall
         li $v0,5
         syscall             #ask user input
         move $t4,$v0        #save a to t1

         mul $s0,$t4,$t4     #get x square
         mul $s0,$s0,$t1     #get a x square

         mul $s1,$t2,$t4     #get bx

         add $s2,$s0,$s1     #get a x square + bx
         add $s2,$s2,$t3     #get a x square + bx + c


         li $v0,4
         la $a0,result       #it will print prompt
         syscall

         li $v0,1
         move $a0,$s2
         syscall

exit:
         li $v0, 10          #syscall 10 terminates program 
         syscall             #and exits
```

When I run the code on Qtspim it will shows error that "Instruction references undefined symbol at la $a0, askA"

Comment: Sorry, code unreadable.  Have a look and please reformat.

Comment: Well, there _is_ no label named `askA` in the code you've shown us, so I'm not sure what you expected. There's an `skA` label, so I suppose that's a typo that you should fix.

Comment: I see, when I change askA to skA, this format works but I don' know why sometimes the result is always 0 when I use QtSpim to run the code